# Sending string filepath in setResult()

Tags: android

I have created a file explorer and a separate app with an editText to display some data. But how do I send the filepath back? I have stored the filepath in a string variable.

Comment: pass the string back in setResult as you specified

Answer (score 1):

You can use startActivityForResult:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);//
```

To pass result back :

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",path_string);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

For more explanation, see the [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)